# Alpha mask/texture physics body fatal error on launch - swift

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics, mask, skphysicsbody

So, i am creating a game and I'm trying to code physics boundaries for the hero so he doesn't just fall through the floor on launch lol, So i implemented my scene and I'm trying to create an alpha mask texture physics body on my "desertForeground" and i don't get any errors, however it keeps crashing and i get this error and the debugging doesn't tell me much, it just basically says invalid instruction but doesn't tell me why is wrong. [image: Error screenshot]   Can anybody help me out? I'm pretty new to coding physics bodies in swift

```
import SpriteKit

enum BodyType:UInt32 {

case hero =    01

case bullet1 = 010

case enemy1 =  0100
case enemy2 =  01000
case enemy3 =  010000

case desertForegroundCase = 02
}
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let desertBackground = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "RZ- 
DesertBackground.png")
let desertForeground = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "RZ-
DesertForeground.png")
let desertgully = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "RZ-DesertGully.png")

     override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
       CreateScene()
}
    func CreateScene (){

    desertForeground.position = CGPoint(x: 570 , y: 102)
    desertForeground.size = CGSize (width: 1136, height: 200)
    desertForeground.zPosition = 1

    let desertForegroundTexture = SKTexture()
    let desertForegroundBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
    desertForegroundTexture, size: CGSize(width: 1136, height: 200))

    desertForeground.texture = desertForegroundTexture

    desertForegroundBody.dynamic = true
    desertForegroundBody.affectedByGravity = false
    desertForegroundBody.allowsRotation = false
    desertForegroundBody.categoryBitMask = 
                   BodyType.desertForegroundCase.rawValue
    desertForegroundBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue 
    | BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
      BodyType.soldierL.rawValue | BodyType.soldierT.rawValue

    desertForeground.physicsBody = desertForegroundBody
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you populate `desertForegroundTexture`.

Replace this

```
let desertForegroundTexture = SKTexture()
```

with this

```
let desertForegroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue come when you try to create a `physicBody` from an empty texture:

```
/**
     Creates a body from the alpha values in the supplied texture.
     @param texture the texture to be interpreted
     @param size of the generated physics body
     */
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    public /*not inherited*/ init(texture: SKTexture, size: CGSize)
```

In fact, for example this kind of thing don't happened if your try to create a `SKSpriteNode` like this:

```
let desertForegroundTexture = SKTexture()
desertForeground = SKSpriteNode(texture: desertForegroundTexture, size:CGSize(width: 1136, height: 200))
```